# I can't print a value from html select menu with if statements (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, user-input

I've had trouble with these for a while, I can't figure out how to make the variable(**seating**) equal to either 'Balcony', 'Lower Area', Level One'  or 'level Two'.

I have tried using .select, making some array that I failed on, .checked .

I need to be able to make the **seating** variable equal to one of the value according to what bit of the select menu they pick(I am using if statements)

I will add my html and Javascript below.

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Preferred Seating:</label> <!-- Following drop down checkbox -->
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" class="lowerLvl" id="lowerArea" >Lower Area($200)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="150" class="levelOne" selected="selected" id="levelOne">Level 1($150)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="100" class="levelTwo" id="levelTwo">Level 2($100)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" class="balcony" id="balcony">Balcony($200)</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <!--End of DropDownBoxes-->
    <!--START OF CHECK BOXES-->

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

        <legend>Prefered night:</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value=""  checked="checked" /></option>
        <label for="checkbox1_0">Thursday</label>
        <br />
            <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="" />
                <label for="checkbox1_1">Friday</label>
                <br /><!--Break as on Example-->
                    <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
                    <label for="checkbox1_2">Saturday</label>
      </fieldset><!-- Above are check boxes -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Subscribe to weekly newsletter: </legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="newletter" id="news" class="custom" value="" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
<!--END OF CHECK BOXES-->
<!--Put a tick box here that asks for weekly mail-->
         <button type="submit" value="Register" onClick="validateGalaOrder()"></button>
            <p id="OrderInput"></p><!--USERS INPUT RETURNS TO THIS <P>-->
            <p id="tktCost"></p>
            <p id="orderErrorMsg"></p><!--INCORRECT INPUT MESSAGES RETURN TO THIS <P>-->
```

Below is my JavaScript.

Please note that some of the JavaScript is from other parts of html above the select menu.

At the moment I am getting the 'value' from the select menu(this is in the else statement under the variable **cost**)

```
function validateGalaOrder() {
    var orderErrorMsg = "";
    var OrderInput = "";
    var ValidateOrderName = document.getElementById('txtOrderName').value;
    var numTickets = document.getElementById('numTickets').value;
    var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail');
    var filter = /*Email Symbol and letter Validator*/ /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/; //This filters out the email input

    var lowerLvl = document.getElementById('lowerArea').value;
    var lvlOne = document.getElementById('levelOne').value;
    var lvlTwo = document.getElementById('levelTwo').value;
    var Balcony = document.getElementById('balcony').value;

    var cost = '';
    var seating = '';
    var prefNight; //This will contain the prefered night and print it
    var newsLetter; //Has details about if they have chosen the newsletter or not.


    if (ValidateOrderName.length <= 2) {
        orderErrorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter a valid name with a length of at least 3 letters</b>");
        document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = orderErrorMsg;
        document.getElementById('txtOrderName').value = ''; //will clear input field if false.
        document.getElementById('txtOrderName').focus(); //this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong. 
        //alert("-ERROR- Please enter a name more than one letter!"); 
        document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = ''; //If someone decides to change there input and that changed input is wrong then this will clear the other data from under the button and just show the error message

        return false;
    }


    if (!filter.test(Orderemail.value)) {
        orderErrorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please provide a valid email address.</b>");
        document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = orderErrorMsg;
        document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value = '';
        document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').focus(); //this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.   
        // alert('Please provide a valid email address');
        document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = ''; //If someone decides to change there input and that changed input is wrong then this will clear the other data from under the button and just show the error message
        return false;
    }

    if (numTickets <= 0) {
        orderErrorMsg += ("<b>-ERROR- Please enter an amount of tickets greater than zero</b>");
        document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = orderErrorMsg;
        document.getElementById('numTickets').value = '';
        document.getElementById('numTickets').focus(); //this Focuses on textbox if input is wrong.
        /*alert("-ERROR- Please enter a mobile number with exactly 10 numeric digits");*/
        document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = ''; //If someone decides to change there input and that changed input is wrong then this will clear the other data from under the button and just show the error message
        return false;
    } else {
        if (document.getElementsById('lowerArea').checked == true) {
            seating = "Lower Area";
        }

        if (document.getElementsById('levelOne').checked == true) {
            seating = "Level One";
        }
        if (document.getElementsById('levelTwo').checked == true) {
            seating = "Level Two";
        }
        if (document.getElementsById('balcony').checked == true) {
            seating = "Balcony";
        }

        //Below is the checkbox printing
        if (document.getElementById('checkbox1_0').checked == true) {
            prefNight = 'Thursday';
        }
        if (document.getElementById('checkbox1_1').checked == true) {
            prefNight = 'Friday';
        }
        if (document.getElementById('checkbox1_2').checked == true) {
            prefNight = 'Saturday';
        }
        //Above is the checkbox printing
        if (document.getElementById('news').checked == true) {
            newsletter = "You wish to recieve our weekly E-mail";
        }
        if (document.getElementById('news').checked == false) {
            newsletter = "You do not wish to recieve our weekly E-mail";
        }
        cost = parseInt(document.getElementById('selectmenu').value, 10) * numTickets; //This calculates the cost(selectMenu*numTickets)
        var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value; //This will grab the email value Inputed.

        OrderInput += ("Your details are: <br />" + "Your E-mail address is: " + Orderemail + "<br />" + newsletter + "<br /> <br />" +
            "You have the following tickets reserved: <br />" + numTickets + " on " + prefNight + " and your seating is :" + seating + "<br /> <br />" + "The total cost of your order will be: $" + cost);
        document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = OrderInput; //This prints the users details to a html element.
        document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = ''; //Removes error messages when everything is correct.

    }
    return true;
}
```

Just a quick reminder of what I am trying to do:

I need to print a **seating** variable value to the **OrderInput** variable.

This **Seating** variable need to either be **'lower area', 'level one' 'balcony' or 'level two'** Depending on what they click on(the options)

Comment: You've to re-think the whole logic. It's not useful to refer to values of individual `option`s, rather refer to the value of the `select` element itself. That contains the value of the selected option.

Comment: I'm new to this :\, Is there a way to get the innertext.split? @Teemu

Comment: Add this to the answer provided by flowstoneknight: `.split('(')[0]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT 2: `seating = document.getElementById('selectmenu').options[document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex].text.split('(')[0]`

Thanks to Teemu for catching that.

EDIT: After looking at your code, I guess you can just declare the variable as `seating = document.getElementById('selectmenu').options[document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex].text`.

Get the `<select>` element's `.selectedIndex` and use that to get its `.options[selectedIndex].text`, which is the text you want.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rg97zvm9/).

Comment: Hi, Where would I add the function? As I have an onClick function that verifies everything else.

Comment: Thanks a lot man! This has helped me so much.. Working perfectly now... I will post my correct code below

Answer (score 0):

So @flowstoneknight has produced the correct answer. My new code is below. I now can get the value and multiply it by the number of tickets inputted aswell as Print the name of the seat in the **orderInput**

my html(It hasn't changed')

```
    <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
      <label for="selectmenu" class="select">Preferred Seating:</label> <!-- Following drop down checkbox -->
      <select name="selectmenu" id="selectmenu">
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" class="lowerLvl" id="lowerArea" >Lower Area($200)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="150" class="levelOne" selected="selected" id="levelOne">Level 1($150)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="100" class="levelTwo" id="levelTwo">Level 2($100)</option>
        <option name="selectmenu" value="200" class="balcony" id="balcony">Balcony($200)</option>
      </select>

    </div>
    <!--End of DropDownBoxes-->
    <!--START OF CHECK BOXES-->

    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">

        <legend>Prefered night:</legend>
     <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_0" class="custom" value=""  checked="checked" /></option>
        <label for="checkbox1_0">Thursday</label>
        <br />
            <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_1" class="custom" value="" />
                <label for="checkbox1_1">Friday</label>
                <br /><!--Break as on Example-->
                    <input type="radio" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1_2" class="custom" value="" />
                    <label for="checkbox1_2">Saturday</label>
      </fieldset><!-- Above are check boxes -->
    </div>
    <div data-role="fieldcontain">
      <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
        <legend>Subscribe to weekly newsletter: </legend>
        <input type="checkbox" name="newletter" id="news" class="custom" value="" />
      </fieldset>
    </div>
<!--END OF CHECK BOXES-->
<!--Put a tick box here that asks for weekly mail-->
         <button type="submit" value="Register" onClick="validateGalaOrder()"></button>
            <p id="OrderInput"></p><!--USERS INPUT RETURNS TO THIS <P>-->
            <p id="tktCost"></p>
            <p id="orderErrorMsg"></p><!--INCORRECT INPUT MESSAGES RETURN TO THIS <P>-->
```

Here is the snippet of my Javascript, Please note I am only posting the select menu part which is in the else statement.

```
var seating = '';

seating = document.getElementById('selectmenu').options[document.getElementById('selectmenu').selectedIndex].text.split('(')[0]         
            cost = parseInt(document.getElementById('selectmenu').value,10) * numTickets;//This calculates the cost(selectMenu*numTickets)
            var Orderemail = document.getElementById('txtOrderEmail').value;//This will grab the email value Inputed.

        OrderInput +=("Thanks " + ValidateOrderName + " for your order!<br /> <br />" + "Your details are: <br />" + "Your E-mail address is: " + Orderemail + "<br />" + newsletter + "<br /> <br />" +
        "You have the following tickets reserved: <br />" + numTickets +" on " + prefNight + " and your seating is :" +  seating + "<br /> <br />" +  "The total cost of your order will be: $" + cost); 
                document.getElementById('OrderInput').innerHTML = OrderInput;//This prints the users details to a html element.
                    document.getElementById('orderErrorMsg').innerHTML = '';//Removes error messages when everything is correct.

    }   
    return true;

}
```